# Hacer consulta con JOIN en varias tablas en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estoy realizando una aplicación en Spring Boot para un consumo de servicios desde el lado del FrontEnd en otro entorno (Angular), sin embargo, deseo realizar una consulta en SQL en particular a través de Spring Boot para obtener el rol de un usuario.

La consulta en SQL realmente funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT u.nombreUsuario, r.nombreRol 
FROM roles_usuarios ru 
JOIN roles r ON ru.ROL_idRol = r.idRol
JOIN usuarios u ON ru.Usuario_idUsuario = u.idUsuario
WHERE u.idUsuario LIKE 4;
```

------ Repositorio -----

```
    @Query("SELECT u.nombreUsuario, r.nombreRol " +
            "FROM RolUsuario ru " +
            "JOIN Rol r ON ru.idRol = r.idRol " +
            "JOIN Usuario u ON ru.idUsuario = u.idUsuario " +
            "WHERE u.idUsuario LIKE (:idUsuario) ")
    Usuario obtenerRol(Integer idUsuario);
```

---------- Servicio --------

```
    public Usuario obtenerRol(Integer idUsuario){
        Usuario rolUsuarioValidation = usuarioRepository.obtenerRol(idUsuario);
        if (rolUsuarioValidation == null) throw new NotFoundException("El usuario no tiene ningún rol", "usuario_not_rol");
        return rolUsuarioValidation;
    }
```

------- Controlador -------

```
    @GetMapping("/obtenerRol/{idUsuario}")
    public Usuario obtenerRol(@PathVariable("idUsuario") Integer idUsuario){
        return usuarioService.obtenerRol(idUsuario);
    }
```

Sin embargo, la aplicación me saca el siguiente error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.eam.RestaurantApp.entity.Usuario]

Y en el postman el siguiente:

> "message": "Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.eam.RestaurantApp.entity.Usuario] for value '{JUAN ADOLFO HERNANDEZ, ADMINISTRADOR}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.eam.RestaurantApp.entity.Usuario]",

Comment: Que campos tiene tu entidad usuario?, porque en tu repositorio la entidad que tratas de devolver es Usuario, sin embargo en el query devuelves otros datos en lugar de la entidad usuario, por eso falla la conversión

Comment: Si quieres devolver solo el nombre de usuario y el rol, podrias hacer un implement de tu repositorio y devolver una clase response

Comment: Sí, realmente la entidad no cuenta con esos atributos, voy a revisar la clase response.